# Firebird 2.5 Consulta de uma procedure

Tags: sql, firebird-2.5

**Eu estou usando esse código para trazer todos os atendimentos dos meses anteriores sendo -1 o mês passado, -2 o mês anterior ao mês passado, porém eu preciso trazer os 3 resultados ( -1, -2 ,-3 ) o que devo modificar ?**

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM R_ATENDIMENTOS_TRIMESTRE (:I_ENTIDADE, :I_LOCAL)
where cast(substring(data_atendimento from 6 for 2) as integer) = cast(substring(CURRENT_DATE from 6 for 2) as integer) - 3
and extract(year from data_atendimento) = extract (year from current_date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela SQL de seu post, imagino que você quer limitar ao ano corrente. Se for este o caso, não fica difícil:

`SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM   R_ATENDIMENTOS_TRIMESTRE (:I_ENTIDADE, :I_LOCAL)
where  extract(month from data_atendimento) between 
         extract(month from current_date) - 3 and 
         extract(month from current_date) - 1 and 
       extract(year from data_atendimento) = 
         extract (year from current_date)`

Se você quiser os meses anteriores, independentemente do ano, será necessário implementar alguma procedure para lidar com a lógica das datas. Por exemplo:

`SET TERM ^ ;`

create or alter procedure MES_ANTERIOR (
    QUANTIDADE integer,
    MES_ATUAL integer,
    ANO_ATUAL integer)
returns (
    MES_ANTERIOR integer,
    ANO_ANTERIOR integer)
as
begin
  ANO_ANTERIOR = ANO_ATUAL;
  MES_ANTERIOR = MES_ATUAL;
  WHILE (QUANTIDADE > 0) DO
  BEGIN
    MES_ANTERIOR = MES_ANTERIOR - 1;
    if (MES_ANTERIOR = 0) then
    BEGIN
      MES_ANTERIOR = 12;
      ANO_ANTERIOR = ANO_ANTERIOR - 1;
    END
    QUANTIDADE = QUANTIDADE - 1;
  END
  suspend;
end^

SET TERM ; ^

Dessa forma, a SQL poderia ficar assim:

`select count(*)
from   R_ATENDIMENTOS_TRIMESTRE (:I_ENTIDADE, :I_LOCAL)
where  extract(year from data_atendimento) * 100 + extract(month from data_atendimento) between
       (select ANO_ANTERIOR * 100 + MES_ANTERIOR from MES_ANTERIOR(
         3,
         extract(month from current_date),
         extract(year from current_date))
       ) and
       (select ANO_ANTERIOR * 100 + MES_ANTERIOR from MES_ANTERIOR(
         1,
         extract(month from current_date),
         extract(year from current_date))
       )`